# Visual Studio Forms: Locate Image File of PictureBox?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, picturebox

I am not new to VS, but relatively new to the "forms" design feature. I recently pulled down a project from source that includes a form with a PictureBox of a logo. When I look at the PictureBox's properties, the Image field (as well as the ErrorImage and InitialImage fields) reads "System.Drawing.Bitmap" and shows a small picture of the logo. When I click the ellipses next to the Image field, I am shown a window titled "Select Resource", but browsing or otherwise, still cannot find the actual image file.

When designing or running the project, the PictureBox shows an image of our company logo, so I assume it must be referencing some file.

Is there a way to see exactly what file is the image resource for this picture box? I would think that either I am new to forms and don't know exactly where to look, or somehow the VS project or some other construct has wrapped up the OG file into some sort of internal bitmap or something more ethereal. Either way I've been snooping around to no avail.

Any direction would be appreciated!

Comment: You need to import the image to add to the picture box by clicking on ellipses.

Comment: The image is visible, both when using the form designer and when running the solution. I can see the logo in both instances just fine. This is why I would assume there is an image resource somewhere, because the form is displaying a very specific logo. I might've been unclear, I'll edit the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If "System.Drawing.Bitmap" is the Image field's value, it means you can find it in the form resource file.

If your form is named Form1.cs, the resource file will be named Form1.resx.cs.  You can see that file when you click the little "+" next to your form in solution explorer.

Comment: Hmmm. I've actually checked there, I'm working with an "about box" so it's named AboutBox1.resx.cs, and am not finding any resources listed other than one text resource which is just a string used in the description.

Comment: in the top left corner of the resource  form, there's a drop down.  You need to select "Images".

Comment: That did it! Shoot, I really had trouble finding that. And from there I can export it so that's perfect. Thanks for the help.